# toString() for a List Stack

Tags: java

i have a class for List, Node, and Stack.

The classes List, Node are all done, now i want to finish my Stack.class, which uses my List.class.
Now i am in my main method and i want to try out my push/pop methods, but don't know how to output them as strings.

I did this in my List.class, but don't know how to recreate it for the Stack.class.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
public class Stack {
    private List list;
    
    public Stack() {
        list = new List();
    }


public class List{

public String toString() { 
        Node temp = head;
        String string = "";
        while (temp != null && temp.getNext() != null) {
            string = string + temp.getElement() + ", ";
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        if (temp != null) {
            string = string + temp.getElement() + ".";
        }
        return string;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Stack` class, you could invoke `list.toString()`. Something like

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Stack: %s", list.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to "concatenate" the 2 toString() method.
So you have to create a new toString() in your Stack class.

```
public class Stack {
    private List list;
    
    public Stack() {
        list = new List();
    }

public String toString()
{
String myreturn = "//Anything you need" + list.toString();
return myreturn;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle each element in the list:

For example, if you need get list values by comma separate:

```
public String toString() {
    return list.stream()
                .map(Objects::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Or you need also modify each value:

```
public String toString() {
    return list.stream()
                .map(p -> "[" + p.toString() + "]")
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```